# Android: Show and Hide Editext on press of a button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Initially, I want to display 2 EditText by default and if the user wants to add more EditText, they should use a button which allows them to display upto 3 more EditTexts and a hide button if the user doesn't want to show the EditText

Any suggestions on how do I go on doing about this?

```
    inputOptionName1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.optionName1);
    inputOptionName2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.optionName2);
    inputOptionName3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.optionName3);
    inputOptionName4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.optionName4);
    inputOptionName5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.optionName5);
```

Right now this is my code which just shows the 5 EditTexts...

Do I have to put this in Arraylist and do if and else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
inputOptionName1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
inputOptionName2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
inputOptionName3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
inputOptionName4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
inputOptionName5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In your `JAVA` **global**

```
int count = 2;
```

In your `JAVA` **onCreate()**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(count >= 5)
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No more EditText Box to add.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                  count++;

                  if(count == 3)
                   inputOptionName3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  else if(count == 4)
                   inputOptionName4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  else if(count == 5)
                   inputOptionName5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

 cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(count <= 2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No more EditText Box to cancel.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     if(count == 3)
                     inputOptionName3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     else if(count == 4)
                     inputOptionName4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     else if(count == 5)
                      inputOptionName5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                     count--;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: how do I loop them together? Like, if only 2 options are visible only allow the user to add another option but if option3 is visible, remove or add another option.

Comment: what do you mean by java globally?

Comment: @Rager58 it's all spelling mistake i edited try my codes. it's global.

Comment: giving me this at count++ syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

Answer (score 0):

in onCLick() of a Button, you could do something like

```
inputOptionName1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
inputOptionName2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
inputOptionName3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
inputOptionName4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
inputOptionName5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this: position is important to you as you are looking to add dynamically upto 3 more editText start form 2 edittext Always visiable. You can choose `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` which you [#View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) want.

// In your xml

```
inputOptionName1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
inputOptionName2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
inputOptionName3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
inputOptionName4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
inputOptionName5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

// In your Java code-

```
 public static int position = 2;

 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(position < 5)
               {
                inputOptionName+(++position).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
            }
        });

 cancle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                if(position > 2)
               {
                    inputOptionName+(--position).setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
                }
            });
```

Comment: you need to modify `inputOptionName+(--position)` and `inputOptionName+(++position)` to get it executable.

Comment: I expect that, basically I have tried to give you some idea how to do that. Can you please try that `(EditText)(("inputOptionName"+(--position)).toString()).setVisibility(View.GONE);` got my point.